# cqpweb triggers error "DATABASE CACHE OVERLOAD!"

Tags: 14.04, mysql, php, lamp

cqpweb is a web interface to corpora programmed in php and using a mysql database. We run it successfully (and for quite a time unchanged) on our server, but during the last week or so, some database queries started fail consistently.

We run ubuntu 14.04 LTS and do regular upgrades with `apt-get upgrade`. Otherwise, we did not change the system configuration. I checked that disk space is not a problem.

Current versions of programs:

php --version
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.24 (cli) (built: Mar 16 2018 12:41:43) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies

mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.59, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

What can cause a database cache overload and how can I cure it? Rebboting the server does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to an inquiry on the [CWB mailing list](http://devel.sslmit.unibo.it/mailman/listinfo/cwb) I have learned that the cache in question is maintained by the application (`cqpweb`) and that the Ubuntu upgrades on php and mysql aren't the problem.

In my case, the solution is to enlarge the application cache.